# keeping GridView checkbox state when posting back

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView which with a CheckBox in a TemplateField.

When I check something and hit the submit button, the items that I have checked are not check on the postback.

I tried using `EnableViewState` and that did not help.

How can this be fixed?

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>               
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SELECT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ICAO" HeaderText="ICAO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IATA" HeaderText="IATA" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AIRPORT_NAME" HeaderText="AIRPORT NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CITY" HeaderText="CITY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTRY" HeaderText="COUNTRY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="REVISED_DATE" HeaderText="REVISED DATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL_DATE" HeaderText="EMAIL DATE" />          
        </Columns>            
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you are missing the server side code (the VB.NET)

Comment: Im not having it do anything yet, thats why i didnt put in the server side code, all im doing is hitting submit. The checkboxes should stay check through a postback, correct?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829135/gridview-doesnt-remember-state-between-postbacks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override LoadViewState and SaveViewState methods to maintain the selection.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153240/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110205-1.aspx#postadlink